# Storing dynamic user generated fields in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm storing data in a collection for *rules*. These rules are user defined and can vary, and they will be used to check data from an API. I.e. a user may define that if the field spend (taken from an API) is higher than x do y (i.e. notify Slack).

Each "campaign" can have different rules, and users can set these based on a handful parameters, with a logic comparison to a defined value. A campaign can have many rules, and rules can be used across many campaigns.

It's for an internal tool written in python 3.5

My first intuition was something like:

```
`{
"rulename" : "test123",
"campaigns" : [
    "123456",
    "765434"
],
"triggers" : [
        {
            "impressions": "500",
            "comparison": ">"
        },
        {
            "cost": "1.5",
            "comparison": ">"
        }
],
"action" : "notify"
}`
```

Here's a picture of user input to better illustrate: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ai745inl2quwdh8/Screenshot%202017-07-09%2022.50.20.png?dl=0

The rules will be used with api requests, and if the rules are triggered (i.e. the API says impression are above 500 AND cost is higher than 1.5, then do something.

I hope it makes sense. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Better for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ . This site is for questions with one good answer, you're asking for expert opinion on your design.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that. I'll post it there instead.

Comment: ""Questions must involve real code that you own or maintain. Pseudocode, hypothetical code, or stub code should be replaced by a concrete implementation. Questions seeking an explanation of someone else's code are also off-topic." – alecxe, Graipher, Jamal"

So back here ..